# How to bind keyboard shortcuts to Office AddIn Commands?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

AddIn Commands can open Taskpanes and Execute javascript functions. It would be very useful to be able to bind keyboard shortcuts to them which I presume would happen in the Manifest file?

Cannot find any documentation on this though...

Comment: Cindy is right that it's not currently supported -- but I recommend you add a comment and/or upvote a suggestion about it on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/6572900-add-keyboard-shortcut or related threads.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe it's not supported.

In the Office applications, a direct connection to the keyboard is only possible using VBA.

For "automation" (VSTO, COM Add-ins, etc.) it's necessary to use Windows API keyboard hooks (that don't always function well).

Given the JS "sandboxing" I don't think it's possible, anymore than calling JS functionality from VBA or the reverse.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/keyboard-shortcuts